# Simple number guessing game using binary search algorithm in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, binary-search

This program requires me to: *Write a program that plays a simple number-guessing with its user. The user thinks of a number and then answers a series of questions asked by the computer until it correctly guesses the
number.*

My problem is that the compiler says that: *'arr' undeclared (first use in this function)*

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "strlib.h"
#include "simpio.h"

#define size 200

int binSearch (int num);
void getArray (int arr[]);

main()
{
      printf("Think of a number in the range of 1-200 and I'll guess it.\n");
      int arr[size];
      getArray(arr);
      binSearch(arr);
      getchar();
}

void getArray (int numbers[])
{
      int number;

      for(number=1;number>=200;number++)
      {
                 arr[number]=number;                                 
      }    
}

int binSearch(int num)
{
      int low, high, mid;
      string strReply;

      low=0;
      high=size-1;

      while(low<=high);
      {
                 mid=low+high/2;
                 printf("\nIs the number %d ?\t", mid);
                 strReply= GetLine();
                 if(StringEqual(strReply, "no"))
                 {
                          printf("Is the number less than %d ?\t", mid);
                          if(StringEqual(strReply, "no"))
                          { 
                                     high=mid-1;                         
                          }
                          else if(StringEqual(strReply, "yes"))
                          {
                                     low=mid+1;     
                          }
                 }
                 else if(StringEqual(strReply, "yes"))
                 { 
                          return(mid);     
                 }
                 else
                 {
                          return(-1);    
                 } 
}
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Did you check the line associated to the message the compiler outputted? Or did you try to check your code for occurencies of arr? I see at least 1 spot where you use arr without having it declared...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
void getArray (int numbers[])
{
  int number;

  for(number=1;number>=200;number++)
  {
             arr[number]=number;     // this should be numbers[number]                            
  }    
}
```

You pass the array to the function, but use the array as if it were global.

Comment: I did this but at binSearch(arr), the compiler says: [Warning] passing arg1 of binSearch makes integer form pointer without cast.

Comment: @C_Beginner_Learner Did you check the prototype you declared for binSearch? What do you think chould the compiler message mean? - Let me tell you that especially as a C beginner learner you should start to learn to understand the compiler messages because they will accompany you for your whole career as a C programmer and give important hints about possible programming Errors.

Answer (score 2):

What @Adrian Jandl said.

Also note your loop is wrong twice:

```
for(number=0; number<200; number++) ...
```

1. Arrays are zero based in C.
2. You count *while number<200*, not *until number>=-200*.

Comment: I've changed that, but the compiler says:  [Warning] passing arg1 of binSearch makes integer form pointer without cast.

Comment: That's because binSearch wants an int, and you pass it your `arr`, which is an array and not an int.

Answer (score 1):

arr is not defined or declared in getArray function. And also arr is not global variable. You can move arr int main() function to global area.